# Only first few multithreaded clients can read response from socket

Tags: c, sockets

I am building a client-server program in C using sockets.  Both my client and my server use a fixed number of threads to operate.  I tested with very few client and server threads at first (5 and 3) and everything seemed to work fine.  But now I tried to up the number of client threads to 500 (while the number of server thread stays at 3), but everything breaks.  The first hundred or so client can send their request and receive a response, but the others don't receive anything from the server.

I'm working on a Debian Windows Subsystem if that changes anything.

I have also tried upping the number of server thread to 300 but the problem still happens.

Here is my (very) simplified code.

### Client thread

```
  int client_socket= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(2018);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
  memset(&addr.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(addr.sin_zero));
  connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));

  int response;
  int cid = 1;

  send(client_socket, &cid, sizeof(int), 0);

  int len = read_socket(socket, &response, sizeof(int), 1000);
  if (len == 0) {
      printf("No response");
  } else {
      printf("Response");
  }
  close(client_socket);
```

### Server thread

```
int socket_fd, cid, len;
while (1)
  {
    socket_fd =
        accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&thread_addr, &socket_len);
    if (socket_fd> 0) {
        int cid;
        int len = read_socket(socket_fd, &cid, sizeof(cid), 1000);
        if (len == 0) {
          printf("Nothing");
        }
        send(socket_fd, &cid, sizeof(int),0);
        close(socket_fd);
    }
  }
```

And here is my helper function `read_socket()`

```c
ssize_t read_socket(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t obj_sz, int timeout) {
  int ret;
  int len = 0;

  struct pollfd fds[1];
  fds->fd = sockfd;
  fds->events = POLLIN;
  fds->revents = 0;

  do {
    // wait for data or timeout
    ret = poll(fds, 1, timeout);

    if (ret > 0) {
      if (fds->revents & POLLIN) {
          ret = recv(sockfd, (char*)buf + len, obj_sz - len, 0);
          if (ret < 0) {
            // abort connection
            perror("recv()");
            return -1;
          }
          len += ret;
      }
    } else {
      // TCP error or timeout
      if (ret < 0) {
        perror("poll()");
      }
      break;
    }
  } while (ret != 0 && len < obj_sz);
  return ret;
}
```

Like I said, some client can complete their execution with no problem, but a lot of them don't receive a response from the server.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.   Note: in general, a server should have a single point where is performs a `accept(), start thread, and loop back to accept()` loop.  Then each new connection to the server starts another thread.  That single thread performs all the communication with a single client via the socket returned from `accept()`.   A single server, using a thread pool, etc can handle thousand of client connections

Comment: the server thread is calling `accept()` it should not do so, that call should be in a loop, back in the main line of the server

Comment: the server code is working in 'series' rather than passing a socket, returned by `accept()` to a thread, where the thread then performs all the communication for that one connection.  One result is that the thread has no need for polling,  Just call `recv()`

Comment: The reason why I don't have a thread that sole purpose is to listen to connection is because I want it to work even with just one server thread.  Also, the number of server thread may be different from the number of client thread.

Comment: @user3629249 (forgot to tag)

Comment: You would know a LOT more info about what is going on if the code actually checked for error conditions for each of the calls to C library functions and reported those errors via `perror()`

Comment: What is the last parameter on the call to `listen()`?  Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the code

Comment: the posted code fails to check for when `poll()` returns 0

Comment: regarding: `return ret;` in the function: `read_socket()`  All that is returning is the returned status from the last call to `recv()` not very useful for the caller of that function.

Comment: Due to the code layout, the server is performing everything in series.  That is not fast enough to keep up with a few hundred client communications.  Strongly suggest researching how to properly handle the clients in parallel

Comment: regarding: `socket_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&thread_addr, &socket_len);
    if (socket_fd> 0) {`    1) the call to `accept()` does not change the value in the variable: `socket_fd`.  2) it does return the socket that should be used to communicate with the client.  3) The returned value from `accept()` needs to be checked to assure no error occurred,  4) a NEW socket is returned. for the server to communicate with the client.  Do NOT modify the 'master' socket that the server uses to 'listen()` and `accept()` client connections

Comment: What @user3629249 says: you are destroying the listening socket by overwriting it with the accept() return:(